# what is the usefulness of inner interface in java?

Tags: java, interface, nested

I recently found that java provides the feature to write interface inside an interface. Can anyone please explain what is the usefulness of nested interface and where I can use it?

Comment: "java provides the fetcher to write interface inside an interface" <- what does this mean?

Comment: I mean to say we can write an interface inside an interface. I want to know what is usefulness of that

Comment: Same as the usefulness of a class inside a class, or a class inside an interface, or an interface inside a class ... It's called 'nesting'.

Answer (score 4):

It can be used to specify the input or output of methods. Consider the following example:

```
public interface SomeInterface {

  void doSomethingWithNames(NamedObject n);

  interface NamedObject {

    String getName();

  }

}
```

We do not actually care about how the object is implemented that is passed in, as long as it provides a method `getName()`. Similarly we can use it to specify the output of a method.

One prominent example where this is used is `Map.Entry` of the `Map` interface ([Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html)). Each implementing map class can use it's own entries, as long as they comply with the interface.

Of course you could define these interfaces outside of the parent interface, but this way you make clear, that they belong together and have a strong connection.